# delete prettify symbol

Tags: evil

Suppose that `("lambda" . 955)`, e.g., is contained in `prettify-symbol-alist`. Deleting a character (key `del`; or `x` in evil, `evil-delete-char`), with point on `λ`, results in `ambda`, only the first character is removed.

Instead, I would like to have `lambda` (i.e. `λ`) entirely removed. Is there a function which does that?

Comment: `M-d` perhaps (bound to `kill-word`) or its evil equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty easy: such "prettified symbols" have start/end of their region stored in text properties. So you basically just query that and if it's non-nil, then you know you're dealing with "pretty symbol".

Then solution involves adding an *around*-advice over `delete-backward-char` which would query the aforementioned properties, and remove the region if they're there otherwise call the original `delete-backward-char`.

```lisp
;; an advice around delete-backward-char
(defun delete-backward-pretty-symbol-advice (orig-func n killflag)
  "Remove \"pretty-symbol\" if it's prior to caret, otherwise call
`delete-backward-char'"
  (if-let*
      ((prev-point (when (> (point) (point-min))
                     (- (point) 1)))
       (pretty-start (get-text-property prev-point 'prettify-symbols-start))
       (pretty-past-end (get-text-property prev-point 'prettify-symbols-end)))
      (delete-region pretty-start pretty-past-end)
    (funcall orig-func n killflag)))
(advice-add 'delete-backward-char :around #'delete-backward-pretty-symbol-advice)

;; an advice around evil-delete-char for evil-mode
(defun evil-delete-char-symbol-advice (orig-func beg past-end &optional type register)
  "Include \"pretty-symbol\"s into region calculation for
`evil-delete-char'"
  (let ((new-start
         ;; return `beg' if property is `nil'
         (or (get-text-property beg 'prettify-symbols-start) beg))
        (new-past-end
         (max past-end
              ;; return `0' if property is `nil'
              (or (get-text-property (- past-end 1) 'prettify-symbols-end) 0))))
    (funcall orig-func new-start new-past-end type register)))
(advice-add 'evil-delete-char :around #'evil-delete-char-symbol-advice)
```

With the first advice in your init file, pressing <kbd>Backspace</kbd> should completely remove a "pretty symbol" if it's there.

The second one is for `evil-mode`: pressing <kbd>x</kbd> while in "normal" mode of `evil-mode` while the caret is over a "pretty symbol" should remove it as well.

Comment: This works, thank you! Very interesting :-) I tried to bind it to `evil-delete-char`, which requires the additional arguments `beg` and `end`. Hmm. Any solution for this as well?

Comment: @AloisPichler sure, here's one for `evil-delete-char`. In this case the region is passed over to `evil-delete-char` *(rather than being just "at point")*, so that simplifies the code, and we just use `beg` to query the text property. I don't check full range `beg..end` as I doubt that in practice the function might be called over a string where a "pretty symbol" would be in the middle. Although I suppose a check could be added for `end`, to make sure there's no region that starts in the middle and goes over `end`. I'm not sure how realistic such situation tho.

Comment: I see. Your post helped me a lot, and I am accepting it as answer, thank you. Really clever. If a region is selected, however, this deletes only the prettified character.

Comment: @AloisPichler oh, I see, that's easy to fix. My point was that I didn't know the function is actually called over a region in some circumstances simply because I couldn't find such. But now that you mentioned, I found that pressing <kbd>x</kbd> with region selected does that. I fixed the function, please check if it works okay for you now. I think I accounted for everything this time. We don't need to add a similar check for `beg` because if at `beg` you found a `prettify-symbols-start` text property, it's guaranteed to start *at least* at `beg`, maybe earlier. So no check required.

Comment: @AloisPichler new update, I simplified the `evil-delete-char` advice. Since it works with a region anyway, we can just calculate the new region and always call into the original function with the new endpoints.

Comment: Excellent, it works amazingly! Thank you again. And I managed to rewrite the function `evil-substitute` myself :-)    (I think this functionality should be standard behavior)

Comment: @AloisPichler oh, I think it's a nice idea, you can [create an issue on Evil-mode project](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil/issues) to discuss that with maintainers. It may well be they'd agree with the idea, why not 

Comment: I have found now that there is a subtle issue if `{` or `}` are involved. Deleting any bracket in `{λ}λ` will delete the following prettified letter (here, `λ`) as well; the same with `(λ)λ`.

Comment: @AloisPichler right, sorry about that, I fixed it. It was caused by the terrible naming in both Emacs and Evil, where they call `end` something that is actually a `past-end`. It's actually a popular mistake, e.g. C++ documentation is littered with such terrible naming *(e.g. if you look at docs for `std∷fill`, they call `last` a parameter that is actually a `past_last`)*, which is very sad, as that leads to bugs like this.

Comment: I tried it just now, thank you. It is better :-)  although still minor problems when visualizing, and deleting a part of the string `(λ)λ(λ)λ`. But it is much better indeed.

Comment: @AloisPichler I'm not sure what problems are you referring to. I just created a buffer with `python-mode` and `prettify-symbols-mode` enabled, wrote a string `(lambda)lambda(lambda)lambda` which looks like `(λ)λ(λ)λ`, and deleting every character behaves correctly for me. Deleting a paren between 2 lambdas turns a `λ)λ` to a `lambdalambda` which is what you'd expect as they now form a different string. So… can't seem to see nothing unusual.

Comment: It works excellent, thank you again. Above, this was my fault. Congrats to this really elegant piece of code!

Comment: Hello again. Wouldn't it be simpler to add an advice for the movements `h` and `l` to always move to the beginning (the end, resp.) of the prettified character? Then, `s` (substitute), `y` (yank), `d`(delete) and `x` (delete-char) would work automatically correct, they would not need an advice. (I actually could not remap these on my own, so I am asking the expert.)

Comment: @AloisPichler I am confused. First of all, they already do that: if you press `l` while being at the prettified-character start, it will move you past it. Vice versa for the `h`. But even if they wouldn't, I just don't see how it's relevant to text deletion. You have a larger string rendered as a single character. You need to find out its borders and remove it. And your point is already at the beginning of the character. So why would you need the `evil-backward-char` and `evil-forward-char` *(being run by `h` and `l`)*?

Comment: Hello again. Suppose the text is `abc\lambda` and I'd like to delete, yank, substitute, … this text. In pretty-symbols-mode and visual mode, selecting from left with `l`, will select and highlight `abc\ `; but what should be selected is (unprettified) `abc\lambda`. For `h`, by the way, everything's fine: if the text is `\lambda abc`, say, selecting in visual mode with `h` (to left from right) will select `\lambda abc`, as desired. With that, advices for delete, delete-char, substitute, … would be superfluous.

Comment: @AloisPichler oh, I just tested and I see you're correct. Actually, I think it is a bug that should be fixed in Evil-mode, because it visually selects whole composed character, but selection actually works only on part of it. You can create a report or even a fix into Evil for that. With that said, I think it's a completely separate matter from removing the character at point, because you'd additionally need to enter visual mode, whereas for `delete-char` to work no additional actions required.

Answer (score 2):

You might (or might not) want to customize user option `prettify-symbols-unprettify-at-point`. From the documentation:

If non-nil, show the non-prettified version of a symbol when point is on it.  If set to the symbol ‘right-edge’, also unprettify if point is immediately after the symbol.  The prettification will be reapplied as soon as point moves away from the symbol.  If set to nil, the prettification persists even when point is on the symbol.

I have it set to `'right-edge`, so the issue you wish to solve never arises.